# Get variable div height and plant var into another css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, getelementbyid, var

Geniuses, Is this possible? Please help as my jQuery javascripting is bad.

I need to get the height of a div, which is dynamically created (so has auto height by default) - the dynamic tweet content is also generated by javascript, which I hope isnt causing issues.

See my dynamic div...

```
<div id="tweet-area"></div>
```

I then need to plant the **div#tweet-area** height into the script below...

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: " + variable here + " });
```

So this was my attempt, but not its quite working...

```
var tweetheight = document.getElementById('tweet-area').offsetHeight;

$("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: " + tweetheight + " });
```

Any advice would be hugely helpful thanks.

Josh

---

**UPDATE**

This is the script that works - loaded after the tweet script

```
var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
$("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});
```

Thank you all!

Comment: `$( '#sidebar-wrapper' ).css({ bottom: $( '#tweet-area' ).height() });`

Comment: it's not working still? Though I didnt know you could write it that short. I can see it should work.

Comment: Also notice that you should run it after your #tweet-area has been populated (with tweets).

Comment: Do you execute this AFTER the tweet-area has been added to the DOM?  Also are the tweet inside the tweet-area float: left (or right?)  If they are you'll need to do a clearfix.  You may need to do one anyway.

Comment: It works thanks - I added the script after the tweet area has been added to the DOM. Thanks for all the helpful advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe `$("#sidebar-wrapper").css("bottom", tweetheight);` would do it?

```
var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
```

Has worked for me in getting the height of an element ^

Comment: This is working either, but if I go into my css, and add a bottom height to `#sidebar-wrapper` it works :-/

Comment: thanks worked a beauty!!!! nice one dude! - im guessing getElementById is javascript and height short jQuery :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting a variable name in quotes? That makes it a string. Try this:

```
var tweetheight = document.getElementById('tweet-area').offsetHeight;
$("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});
```

I'd recommend not using jQuery unless necessary, though. The CSS properties could easily be changed without jQuery like this:

```
document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper').style.bottom = tweetheight + 'px';
```

Comment: Yep it was those speech marks, bad syntax - thanks for you help dude